# When distance between the plates is increased, what will happen to the value of the capacitance

Tags: capacitance

When distance between the plates is increased, what will happen to the value of the capacitance. (a) Increases (b) decreases

Comment: Before coming here what have you done to find your answer?

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance):

> In a parallel plate capacitor, capacitance is directly proportional to the surface area of the conductor plates and inversely proportional to the separation distance between the plates.
>
> [image: parallel plate capacitance formula]
>
> where
> C is the capacitance;
> A is the area of overlap of the two plates;
> εr is the relative static permittivity (sometimes called the dielectric constant) of the material between the plates (for a vacuum, εr = 1);
> ε0 is the electric constant (ε0 ≈ 8.854×10−12 F m–1); and
> d is the separation between the plates.